# Error: Number of features of the model must match the input

Tags: python

I am trying to predict the class of an image as 0 or 1. The features are stored in global_feature:

```
# resize the image
image = cv2.resize(image, fixed_size)

####################################
# Global Feature extraction
####################################
fv_hu_moments = fd_hu_moments(image)
fv_haralick   = fd_haralick(image)
fv_histogram  = fd_histogram(image)

###################################
# Concatenate global features
###################################
global_feature = np.hstack([fv_histogram, fv_haralick, fv_hu_moments])
print (global_feature.shape)

# predict label of test image
prediction = clf.predict(global_feature.reshape(1,-1))[0]

# show predicted label on image
cv2.putText(image, train_labels[prediction],(20,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.0, (0,255,255), 3)

# display the output image
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 533 and input n_features is 532
```

I tried to reshape the prediction but it doesn't seem to work. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is pretty clear: the model expects a vector of 533 features, but you're giving it a vector of 532 features. "Predict the result of these 533 things" is not possible if I give you 532 things. So somewhere, you're either missing or have added an extra index. Reshaping won't help because it changes the dimensions of a vector / matrix, but it doesn't change the number of items contained in it.

It may be helpful to proceed as follows:

1. Figure out what the training input to your model looks like, i.e. exactly how many items it should have. If the number is 532, then you've messed up something in training.
2. If the number is 533 then you've done training correctly but messed up something in predicting. Check exactly what your prediction input looks like, and figure out where along the line you're losing an item (going from 533 as the model expects, to 532 as you're giving it).